# Odo 11 Relación entre modelos

Tags: python, odoo

No tengo muy claro cual seria la relación entre pacientes-citas y doctores-citas, alguien podría ayudarme.

```
class centromedico_pacientes(models.Model):
_name = 'centromedico.pacientes'

name = fields.Char(string="Nombre", required=True)
apellidos = fields.Char(string="Apellidos", required=True)
cita = fields.One2many("centromedico.citas","cpaciente",string="Libros")

#relacion con medicos - historial clinico
#relacion con enfermeros - historial clinico
```

class centromedico_citas(models.Model): 
    _name = 'centromedico.citas'

```
fconsulta = fields.Datetime(string="Fecha consulta", required=True)
cpaciente = fields.Many2one('centromedico.pacientes', string="Paciente", required=True, ondelete="cascade")
cdoctores = fields.??('centromedico.medicos', string="Doctor")
#relacion historial clinico
```

class centromedico_medicos(models.Model): 
    _name = 'centromedico.medicos'

```
name = fields.Char(string="Nombre", required=True)
apellidos = fields.Char(string="Apellidos", required=True)
especialidad = fields.Char(string="Especialidad", required=True)
consultas = fields.??('centromedico.citas', string="Consultas")
```